# Multithreading and UI behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a java app in which I use a thread. My thread runs every 20 seconds but, when it runs it kind of blocks the UI ... i. e. whenever the thread is running and the user clicks on button on anything on UI it doesnt respond sometimes.

Could anyone tell me a solution to this problem.

Comment: You need to provide some code samples to show us your background thread and how the UI is working with it.

Comment: The ui thread basically updates a label on UI and there are 5 buttons on the UI

Comment: How does the background thread update this label?  How is the data shared between the background thread and the UI thread?  Please show us some code otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: If the UI freezes when the thread runs, then there's probably something wrong with the way in which you are creating the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in java Swing, any change made to the state of the UI should be done in a single pre-existing thread called the EDT (event-dispatcher thread).

if that's not the case, you typically experience weird glitches / freezes. one of the most common symptom is that part of the UI becomes gray (except since java 1.6, where the ui is still painted like before, but unresponsive).

the good way to go is to use a dedicated method to queue your changes to the UI in the EDT :

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable toRunInEDT);
```

note that if you call invokeLater, the runnable is executed after all currently queued event have been dispatched. that means that the next line of code could be executed **before** the code in the runnable. there is a synchronous version as well (which should not be executed from the EDT):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable toRunInEDT);
```

Comment: note that any code inside a swing listener (like ActionListener on a JButton) **is** executed inside the EDT

Answer (score 3):

Some additional tips, on top of what edralzar said:

You can use the convenience method `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` to check if code is in fact running on the event dispatch thread. And, like edralzar said, any code that creates GUI components, modifies the state of GUI components or reads the state of GUI components should run on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Another thing to consider, however, is that **code running on the EDT should be able to execute rather quickly**. So you cannot just solve things by running everything on the event dispatch thread. If you do the following, your GUI will be frozen for five seconds:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Ignored in this example
            }
        }
    });
```

Why is it frozen? Because all GUI events and GUI updates are performed on the EDT, and if the EDT sleeps for 5000 miliseconds, no GUI updates can be performed during that time.

[This article](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7717) might be an interesting read.

Comment: very good points, the article is interesting. using Java 6's SwingWorker class allows to address the last point (as mentioned in the article)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like the thread you're referring to (that runs every 20 seconds) is also the thread that governs the UI.

The solution is to separate the two processes onto different threads.